# Tornado async yield

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to understand the purpose of the yield to enable async operations in Tornado but its not clear to me why it does not do an async. I have skipped the imports for brevity but this code is complete otherwise. Here is what I am trying to do. When a user does a http get request, I flip a coin. If the coin turns heads, I sleep for 10 sec and print "Hello Heads". If the coin is tails I immediately print "Hello Tails". When I do a curl and it goes to the sleep condition and run curl again I notice that the request is queued (even if the coin is tails). I was expecting the second request to be serviced in its own thread and to quickly return "Hello Tails". What am I missing?

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   @gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
     toss = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
     print("flipped a coin, got", toss)
     if toss == 'H':
        response = yield time.sleep(10)
        self.write("Hello Heads")
     else:
        self.write("Hello Tails")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   tornado.options.parse_command_line()
   application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])
   application.listen(8888)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` is a blocking function. When your code reaches this statement, the whole server (event loop) blocks for 10 seconds.

So, every subsequent request is also delayed until `time.sleep` is resolved.

Use an asynchronous equivalent of `time.sleep` — [`gen.sleep`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep).

This is also mentioned in the [FAQs section](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel) of Tornado docs.